# pip install <.whl file> installs dist_info but doesn't actually install the package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel

I'm trying change my package over from using `setup.py` to using `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`.

My `setup.cfg` is roughly as follows:

```
[metadata]
name = our_name
version = 0.1.1
author = me

[options]
install_requires =
    networkx >= 3.0
```

My code is all under `src`, and I'm relying on the automatic `src-layout` discovery mechanism.

When I run

```
python -m build
```

it generates a proper wheel file (`dist/our_name-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl`).  When I unpack that wheel file, everything is in there properly - it seems to have discovered all my code correctly.

However, when I install it (`pip install dist/our_name*.whl`), only the distribution info directory shows up in `site-packages`.  Because the dist info is there, `pip list` shows it as being there, but because the actual module directory is missing, I can't import anything from my module elsewhere, or do anything with it.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Addendum: Per sinoroc's comment:
`pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

project structure:

```
README.md
requirements.txt
src
  __init__.py
  module_1
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  module_2
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

Wheel contents:

```
__init.py__
our_name-0.1.1.dist-info
  METADATA
  RECORD
  top_level.txt
  WHEEL
module_1
  __init__.py
  foo.py
module_2
  __init__.py
  bar.py
```

Comment: If you add, at least, the contents of `pyproject.toml` as well as the project's directory structure to the question, it will be easier to help you. Maybe also show the listing of the content of the wheel.

Comment: Added those all to the question

Comment: It seems like maybe you misunderstood what the `src` layout is. This project structure your are showing is not a typical `src` layout. There should not be any `src/__init__.py` file. And I am wondering if you really want to have 2 importable top-level packages `module_1` and `module_2`, because it seems to be what you have right now. -- I recommend you look at this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and this [part of *setuptools* doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout) again.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll give it a green check and all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like maybe you misunderstood what the `src` layout is. This project structure your are showing does not have a typical `src` layout. For example there should not be any `src/__init__.py` file. And also I am wondering if you really want to have 2 importable top-level packages `module_1` and `module_2`, because it seems to be what you have right now and that is also not typical.

I recommend you look at [this packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and this [part of *setuptools* documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout) again. Pay attention to the project directory structure.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This is happening to me, too. What a nasty experience. Took me two hours to track this down.

Comment: @djhaskin987 This answers the original question, because according to the person who originally the question it solved their problem and they accepted this answer. Maybe you are encountering a slightly different issue.