# Can't import PYPI package after creating and installing it

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

-- Update

My project is structured as so

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src/
    └── py-map-gen/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── render.py
        ├── funcs.py
        └── mersenne.py
```

My setup.py is like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='py-map-gen',
    version='0.14',
    author='Ford2003',
    author_email='tommyford28@gmail.com',
    description='A package for generating data for a world with a seed.',
    long_description='',
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ],
    install_requires=["numpy", "matplotlib"]
)
```

The `__init__.py` is empty.

I am able to install the package with pip but I get a `ModuleNotFound` error when trying to import with
`import py_map_gen`.

In the site_packages folder in python I can see the dist-info and the code file for my package

Comment: Your layout is wrong. It's neither flat nor src-layout. See the docs at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/

Comment: I've changed into flat layout and followed another tutorial. rebuilt and uploaded the changes and after installing I still can't import the package

Comment: Could it be the same as this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75828200

Comment: @sinoroc I followed this and made progress. and made into a src layout. I'm now getting the actual code as well as dist.info but still unable to import it. I will update the question with how it now looks

Comment: Ok I've managed to get it working I think it was an issue with the dashes in the name. I just deleted the old project and made a new one called pymapgen instead and now works fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Ford03 If possible you should post your own answer with the fixes you needed to make and accept this answer yourself.